# How best to remove an extruded screwhole from a laptop keyboard?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

The replacement keyboard for my laptop has an extra extruded screwhole for which there is no matching gap in the Laptop body, leaving the keyboard unable to be fully installed. The screwhole is in an extruded "peg", and is itself not screwed in.

I have tried using a wire cutter portion of a multitool to cut it, and after that anchoring it down with duck tape and using a sandpaper block, but the result is coming along much slower than desired (I'm trying to be careful to not break it). Any safe and quick ways to remove the screwhole? I don't think drilling an accommodating hole in the laptop will work as there is a chip that may exist where the screwhole tries to go.

[Image of the Extruded Screwhole](https://flic.kr/p/skWE77)

Comment: Oooh, that is too bad. This is probably obvious now, but it appears you have the wrong keyboard. Unfortunately, now you can not return it for the correct one.

Comment: I would try a metal cutting handsaw which is cheaper than a powered saw. Something like this: http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-95693329/stock-photo-hand-saw-for-metal-cutting.html This will work better than multitools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Dremel Rotary](http://www.dremel.com/en-us/Tools/Pages/CategoryProducts.aspx?catid=2013) like tool will cut that off in a second.

Comment: That's probably the right tool.  However, it will spray tiny metal dust that can mess up circuitry.  Cover any electronics while you do it.  When you're done, use a tiny vacuum, like a Dustbuster, and then a damp paper towel to wipe down everywhere, and then dry it well.  You don't want that stuff floating around when you reassemble it.

Comment: I've actually used exactly that tool for exactly the same job. Worked *very* well. Keep a strong vacuum cleaner running while cutting, so it can suck up the metal dust immediately.

Comment: I used a "Pedipaws" clone rotary nail file, and kept a fridge magnet in the path of the shavings. Took around 10 min to get it shaved down and the keyboard now fits. I just wished I put the magnet inside an inside-out sandwich bag to collect the fillings.